# Is there a way to use a function with an ending?

Tags: shell, function

So for example adding an ending to the command would display the ending:

```
function work* () {
     echo "$1";
}

export -f work*
$ working
ing
```

Comment: Why not `t() { printf '%s\n' "$@" }; t ing`?

Comment: I'm trying to make it one word so typing "testing" would run the script

Comment: Additionally, it could be "tested" would run the script and a lot of other endings are possible

Comment: Then it would be `t tested` `t testfoo` `t testbar`, whatever you choice. Also `test` is a standard shell command, you shouldn't overwrite it.

Comment: I didn't realize test was a standard function, my bad. I'll use "work" as the example. But in trying to make the function one word so there would be no spaces between "work" and "ing"

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that would be to create a bunch of symlinks (or aliases) and make the command aware of a) it's **real** name (hard-coded) and b) how it was invoked and then make a "diff" of that.  What's the use-case for this, btw, I find the request fairly pointless =}

Comment: Is it the function you are actually wanting to write, or is it that you'd like to match words with certain endings?  Is this about creating a shell function, or about doing pattern matching on words?

Comment: I had python and a couple of other programs in a directory that was separate from use/bin/ and wanted to call them using single command such as workPython [name of program goes here]. And I wanted to see if this was possible.

Comment: @Anton You wanted to execute them in succession? That's what shell scripts are for...

Comment: No i did not want them recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would do it for you:

```
function work() {
    echo "${1#work}"
}
function err_work() {
    [ "${1#work}" != "$1" ] && work $*
}
trap "err_work \$BASH_COMMAND" ERR
```

The `err_work` function is then invoked on all command errors, to discover that the failing command starts with "work", and thereby invoke the `work` function without ending instead, with the initial command line as arguments.

Of course, bash will complain about the initial command before  invoking the trap, so that will looks a bit ugly; perhaps there is a way to turn that off, though I haven't found any

Comment: Might be better to use `command_not_found_handle`, like one of my answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/943771/158442 (assuming bash)